# Javascript: Best way to get JS to work on a lot of dynamically added HTML content. Delegation/Retriggering/or other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On my website, I have a lot of HTML content added dynamically (from ajax requests) so I have to use delegation quite a lot so the JS code works on the added HTML content. I recently built my own full page ajax where pages load with ajax on every link click and form search. Because of this full page ajax, all of my events must be delegated to the body or document:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').on('click', '.example1', exampleHandler1);
    $('body').on('click', '.example2', exampleHandler2);
    $('body').on('submit', '.example3', exampleHandler3);
    $('body').on('mouseover', '.example4', exampleHandler4);
    // etc.

});
```

I've already got 30 event listeners and I may have over 100 more in the future and so I don't know how much this will impact the performance if I have over 100 of events all delegated to the body.

I'm not sure if the following way would be better:

I could retrigger all the code again whenever the HTML content is added. This will also mean I won't have to use delegation at all:

```
// Trigger the custom event on ready so it runs when a user first visits the page
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).trigger('exampleCustomEvent');
});

// using a custom event
$(document).on('exampleCustomEvent', function() {

    $('.example1').on('click', exampleHandler1);
    $('.example2').on('click', exampleHandler2);
    $('.example3').on('submit', exampleHandler3);
    $('.example4').on('mouseover', exampleHandler4);
    // etc.

});

/**
 * Re-trigger the custom event.
 *
 * Call this whenever dynamic content is added.
 */
function triggerCustomEvent() {

    // Remove any event listeners first
    $('*').off();
    $(window).off();

    // Trigger the custom event
    $(document).trigger('exampleCustomEvent');
}
```

Then I just have to call `triggerCustomEvent()` whenever HTML content is added.

What one would be better, and are there any other solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of functionality you are importing,  you could include the JS needed with the new HTML, or you could even just include a JS call within the HTML to init the functions again.
If the JS functionality is generic and you don't want to pass it with with each call, then i would just recommend initializing just the section. You could even pass the selector for the wrapper to the function that initializes everything and append it to the beginning of each selector.

```
function init(){
    $('#contentWrapper #test').click(function(){console.log("ouch!");})
}

//code from ajax-->:
$('#contentWrapper').html(
'<script>init(); $("#contentWrapper #test").click(function(){'+
'console.log("unique functionality to this ajax call.");})</script>'+
'<button id="test">CLICK ME</button>'
)
```